# java executing shell commands

Tags: java, shell, command, execute

I am writing a java program that needs to execute shell commands, so I wrote a function that would take the command to execute as a string (ie: "mkdir ~/Folder1") and execute that command with the shell.  Here is the function:

```
 private static void shell(String cmd)
 {
   try
   {
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
    pr.waitFor();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
     System.err.println(line); // show any errors returned by the command executed on the error console

    }

   } catch (Exception ee) {}
```

}

for some weird reason this function is not executing any commands.  Did I do this wrong?  It seems like a simple thing to execute shell commands, but it is not working.

Comment: In your `catch` block, do this: `ee.printStackTrace();` And post the errors

Comment: What I saw, is a guy with 10 reputation and 1 gold &1 silver medal... :P

Comment: why does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the command string as some mkdir command like ,
"mkdir C:\some\folder\path".

mkdir is not some binary in Windows path, it's a parameter to command line.
Use the command string as "cmd.exe /c mkdir C:\some\folder\path"

Then it should work fine.

Comment: I am using a mac (so unix based terminal) and I am familiar with using the mkdir command directly in the terminal.  I do not think the string you supplied would do anything.  I am using different code and it stil is not working: (oh I can't post it, fun)